Vw golf 1 painting metallic paint
I sprayed a single coat metallic base and noted that I was short of paint for another coat. I have now bought the paint with same color code and it has been a week now. What should I do now? Please help

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Note, I'm not a body guy, so leaving this as a comment. Since the paint has sat for a week, it is fairly much cured, which means if you spray it again as it is, the new paint layer will most likely peel because there's no mechanical adhesion. You're going to have to scuff and clean the paint you laid a week ago so you'll get the adhesion you're  need. I don't know what grit or how you go about doing it, though. Hopefully someone with more experience than I will chime in and give us some facts.

Spray it, no prep needed.  I've done so with spray paint a number of times in my life and never had any adhesion problems or other issues.
